# get_highest_resolution function doesn't work in pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

when i tried to use get_highest_resolution() function to get the highest resolution of the video while downloading with pytube. although it worked fine a week ago but it results in a error now.

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('https://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')
ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
ys.download()
```

> AttributeError : 'nonetype' object has no attribute download

while this works fine :

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('https://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')
ys = yt.streams.first()
ys.download()
```

does anyone know the reason why there is a error while using get_highest_resolution().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pytube
a = '=' * 23

print(f"{a}\n\033[0;31mBAIXAR VÍDEO DO YOUTUBE\033[0;0m\n{a}")

video = pytube.YouTube(input('Digite a URL do vídeo: '))
resolucoes = video.streams.all()

for i in resolucoes:  # mostra as resoluções disponíveis
    print(i)

video.streams.get_by_itag(137).download("D:\Downloads YouTube")  # salva na pasta
```

Comment: Please use international language (English) to explain answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but I used progressive=true and it worked

```
 Label(root,text = 'Youtube Video Downloader', font ='arial 20 
 bold',bg="#336B87",pady=10).pack()

 link = StringVar()

 Label(root, text = 'Paste Link Here:', font = 'arial 15 
 bold',bg="#336B87",pady=0).place(x= 150 , y = 60)
 link_enter = Entry(root, width = 70,textvariable = link).place(x = 
 32, y = 90)

 def Downloader():     
 url =YouTube(str(link.get()))
 video = url.streams.filter(progressive=True).last()
 video.download()
 Label(root, text = 'DOWNLOADED', font = 'arial 15').place(x= 180 , y 
 = 210)
```

Comment: Can you please put your line of code in a context. A more extensive code sample might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

..you tried with another url?

having the same issue i recognized that pytubes get_highest_resolution() does not seem to work on every youtube url, but on most.. (60/40) [if none of your urls work try https://pypi.org/project/pytube3/] think only exception handling will "fix" this.

have a great 2021 everyone!